How to do a GET Request with Fast Endpoints in ASP.NET?
As the title of this question tells, how could I do a GET request with Fast Endpoints in ASP.NET
Now I have tried to do this:
using api.Blogs.Shared;
using api.Data;
using AutoMapper;
using FastEndpoints;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace api.Blogs.ListBlogsEndpoint;
public class ListBlogsEndpoint(BlogDbContext context, AutoMapper.IMapper mapper) : Endpoint<ListBlogsRequest, BlogResponse[]>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Get("blogs");
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(ListBlogsRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var blogs = await context.Blogs.ToArrayAsync(ct);
        var response = blogs.Select(b => mapper.Map<BlogResponse>(b)).ToArray();

        await SendOkAsync(response, ct);
    }
}


But when I try to do a get request I get the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
I don't know what to do now, I have searched about it, and it seems that the Request in a GET request should be query parameters, but they are used here as a body
EDIT: I'm using swagger, and it provide me with a body, so I think if I use postman it would be fine.

In your code, what is ListBlogsRequest? If you want to pass in an id, you can omit it and just pass the id in query parameters as Get("blogs/{id}").

its a simple record
public record ListBlogsRequest(string? query);

most likely you have gotten the middleware setup wrong. the following works out of the box:
var bld = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
bld.Services
   .AddFastEndpoints()
   .SwaggerDocument(); //define swagger doc

var app = bld.Build();
app.UseFastEndpoints()
   .UseSwaggerGen(); //enable swagger middleware
app.Run();

public record ListBlogsRequest(string? Query);

sealed class ListBlogsEndpoint : Endpoint<ListBlogsRequest, string[]>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Get("blogs");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(ListBlogsRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        string[] response = ["one", "two", req.Query!];
        await SendAsync(response);
    }
}


you may have called swagger methods that use swashbuckle (now abandoned), which is not supported by fastendpoints. do the swagger middleware as explained in the docs here.
